# Genitiv von "Hof von König Karl dem Vierten"

Tags: genitive

Was ist der korrekte Genitiv von:

> Ich lebe auf dem Hof von König Karl dem Vierten.

Meine Idee gefällt mir irgendwie nicht wirklich:

> Ich lebe auf dem Hof des König Karl dem Vierten.

Comment: *"Auf dem Hof **von** König..."* ist umgangssprachlich. Sehr schöne Frage übrigens.

Comment: Wenn man "auf dem Hof" schreibt, bedeutet das "ein Hofplatz" (dann ist der arme Mann obdachlos) oder "ein konkreter Bauernhof" (dann hätte Karl IV. auch nur einen einzigen Bauerhof besessen). In diesem Zusammenhang ist wohl eher "zum Hofstaat gehören" gemeint; da sollte man "Ich lebe am Hof König Karls IV." sagen.

Answer (score 14):

> Ich lebe auf dem Hof König Karls des Vierten.

Mit Artikel müsste es heißen „… dem Hof des Königs Karl –“ und wie es dann weiter gehen müsste bin ich nicht wirklich sicher. Also ohne Artikel (ist sowieso sinnvoller) und die Sache ist eindeutiger.

**Edit:**

Beispiele aus [canoo / Satzgliedbau: Nomengruppe: Apposition](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html?MenuId=Sentence325)

> [Beispiele für Apposition als Erweiterung des Herrschernamens]
>
> Die Apposition steht hinter dem Bezugswort und stimmt im Kasus mit ihm überein:
>
> *Elisabeth **die Zweite***
> *mit Elisabeth **der Zweiten***
> *das Leben Elisabeths **der Zweiten***
>
> *Iwan **der Schreckliche***
> *ohne Iwan **den Schrecklichen***
> *das Leben Iwans **des Schrecklichen***
>
> Weiter gilt bei Herrschernamen mit Titel:
>
> Titel als Apposition
>
> *Zarin Katharina die Große*
> *das Leben Zarin Katharina**s** der Großen*
>
> *König Friedrich Willhelm der Erste*
> *das Leben König Friedrich Willhelm**s** des Ersten*
>
> Titel mit Artikel, d. h. Name als Apposition
>
> *die Zarin Katharina die Große*
> *das Leben der Zarin Katharina der Großen*
>
> *der König Friedrich Willhelm der Erste*
> *das Leben des König**s** Friedrich Willhelm des Ersten*

Der Punkt ist, dass es tatsächlich davon abhängt, ob man den Genitiv mit oder ohne Artikel anschließt. Je nachdem ist entweder der Herrschername oder der Titel in den Genitiv zu setzen.

Demnach heißt also die Alternative mit Artikel:

> Ich lebe auf dem Hof des Königs Karl des Vierten.

Bevorzugen würde ich allerdings nach wie vor die Version ohne Artikel.

Comment: Es ist egal, ob da ein Artikel steht oder nicht: Genitiv ist und bleibt Genitiv - m-E. völlig korrekte Antwort!

Comment: @Takkat: Nein, das ist schon wesentlich, ob mit oder ohne Artikel. Lässt man einmal das Zählanhängsel weg, heißt es ohne Artikel „auf dem Hof König Karls“ und mit Artikel „auf dem Hof des Königs Karl“. Siehe http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html?MenuId=Sentence325 (ab „ Weiter gilt bei Herrschernamen mit Titel“)

Answer (score -1):

> Ich lebe auf dem Hof des Königs Karl der Vierte.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Auf wessen Hof? Auf des Königs ([namens] Karl der Vierte) Hof. (sehr unsicher)

Comment: I can't explain it very well beyond "it just sounds right to me", unfortunately - I was really hoping someone would come in with a better explanation. The anon above is right, I think - König needs to be in the genitiv, but Karl der Vierte doesn't because it's not answering the "whose court?" question, it's answering "Who is the king?" I think. Sorry, this isn't very helpful.

Comment: Takkat, do you have a source for that? "Ich lebe auf dem Hof [des] Königs Karl des Vierten" sounds really wrong to me, like you're saying you're living on the court of the king of Karl the 4th, i.e. that the king and Karl are not the same person. But I can't back up my feeling with any grammar resources - I was hoping someone else would be able to.

Comment: @Cassandrexx: unfortunately I am very short of convincing sources. Whoever downvoted your answer should really add their source in an answer! Doing research for *"Karl der Große"* may be more promising.